# Adding google tiles with R

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet

I'm using the `leaflet`package with R to generate interactive maps and I would like to use the Google Maps layer. However Google Maps are not available as an argument of the function `addProviderTiles`.
How can I add these google layers with R ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [base map](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/basemaps.html) of from Google maps. Currently [leaflet supports](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) OpenStreetMap, MapQuestOpen, Stamen, Esri and OpenWeatherMap. If you have access to extra mapping, you can use a WMS tile to serve your own cartography. No google maps, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have found this [document](https://gist.github.com/crofty/2197701#file-index-html) that explains how to use Google Maps with leaflet, but nothing with R.
Is there a simple way to do it with R ?

Answer (score 17):

Try this `leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "https://mts1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&src=app&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=G", attribution = 'Google')`

Comment: Please, can you provide the google maps not google earth layer ? Please

Comment: I found the right URL , here it's `http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga`

Answer (score 1):

I too was searching for the same...
As Roman replied, I am using the following as an alternative

```
leaflet(data = data) %>% addMarkers() %>% addTiles(group = "OSM(default)") %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "ESRI") %>% addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner", group = "Stamen") %>% addLayersControl(baseGroup = c("OSM(default", "ESRI", "Stamen"))
```