# Add wrld3d Maps to R Leaflet Package

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way to add our own third-party tiles to the R leaflet package? I’ve been drooling over [wrld3d](https://www.wrld3d.com/) maps since I discovered them a couple months ago. Thanks!

Comment: The library enables 3rd party tiles already: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/basemaps.html.

Comment: @RyanMorton true, but `wrld3d` doesn't come with a `urlTemplate` such as "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png". It comes with a [javascript API](https://www.wrld3d.com/wrld.js/latest/docs/api/) which seems really promising. I'm trying to see how I can use that within the [tag:r] `leaflet` package without breaking out into JS.

Comment: @aspiringurbandatascientist, sounds like this may be more involved than I originally thought. As far as I can tell, it would be possible to build a R interface to the `wrld3d` javascript API. How to make this play nicely with the R `leaflet` package, I'm not quite sure...

Comment: @PaulGovan agreed. I made an account with `wrld3d` and couldn't figure out how to make it work with `leaflet`. One idea is to delete this question on SO and re-post it on https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues. No guarantee of an answer, but at least we tried here on SO. Or, you could leave the question and edit it until you have some `r` code to share that others could use to try to enable `wrld3d` tiles within `leaflet`. Perhaps the bounty was too small? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303634/what-is-the-accepted-method-of-renewing-interest-in-a-question.

Comment: Yep, already tried that: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/466. I would suggest keeping it open while I explore other options. Maybe someone else will come across it who could provide some insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use addTiles to import additional titles. This example lets you import from Google Earth for instance.

leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "https://mts1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&src=app&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=G", attribution = 'Google')

[Solution provided sourced from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542933/adding-google-tiles-with-r)